# Angular- ng model cannot get the object array value

Tags: html, angular, typescript

have check in and out two dynamic input field . when select the days will let user field in the check in and out time range. The problems are the value and data format cannot get it .**The ng model cannot the check in and check out value.** I want to save the data format like this into the database.

```
{
  "days": {
    "Monday": {
      "checkin": "09:00",
      "checkout": "18:00"
    },
    "Tuesday": {
      "checkin": "07:00",
      "checkout": "19:00"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my html file

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Active Days</label>
            <ng-select [items]="days" name="days"
             bindLabel="id" autofocus loadingText="Loading ..." [multiple]=true
              bindValue="id"  placeholder="Select Active Days" 
              [(ngModel)]="attendanceProfile.daysprofile.dayy" >
            </ng-select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     
      <div *ngFor="let days of attendanceProfile.daysprofile.dayy; let i =index ">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Day</label>
              <input autocomplete="off" atp-time-picker type="text" 
                class="form-control" name="days" id="days"
                [value]="days"
                placeholder="days"  disabled />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Check In Time</label>
              <input autocomplete="off" atp-time-picker type="text" 
              class="form-control" name="checkin" id="checkin"
                [(ngModel)]="attendanceProfile.daysprofile.dayy[i].checkin" placeholder="chcekin" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Check Out Time</label>
              <input autocomplete="off" type="text" 
               class="form-control" name="checkout" id="checkout"
                [(ngModel)]="attendanceProfile.daysprofile.dayy[i].checkout" placeholder="checkout" />
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Here is my component code. try to save it by using the attendanceprofile object.

```
getNewObject(updateDefault: boolean = false): AttendanceProfile {
    let attendanceProfile = new AttendanceProfile();
    attendanceProfile.updatedAt = new Date();
    attendanceProfile.updatedBy = this.configService.currentUser.fullname;
    attendanceProfile.status = 0;
    attendanceProfile.daysprofile= {
        dayy:{['']:{checkin:{},checkout:{}}}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[i].checkin` cannot get the value. try use `checkin[i]` to get the value.